# Allocate resources on tasks

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I'm working on a Resource-Task allocation problem that considers 2 datasets:

1. for each Resource and month I have availability (in working days)
2. for each Task I need certain working days

Is there any possibility in Python to be able to randomly allocate my IDs on certain Tasks (only for a month) to eliminate the working days spent on each task?

I can't imagine a solution without a while loop, but I'd be happy if you could help me. Thank you.

***Example of my Resources dataset (1):***

| id_resource | month | working_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2023-10-01 | 14 |
| 234 | 2023-10-01 | 15 |
| 345 | 2023-10-01 | 12 |
| 456 | 2023-10-01 | 17 |

***Example of my Tasks dataset (2):***

| id_task | month | working_days_needed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-01 | 24 |
| 2 | 2023-10-01 | 27 |
| 3 | 2023-10-01 | 7 |

***Desidered Output:***

| id_task | id_resource | days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 14 |
| 1 | 234 | 10 |
| 2 | 234 | 5 |
| 2 | 345 | 12 |
| 2 | 456 | 10 |
| 3 | 456 | 7 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

resources = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [123, 234, 345, 456],
    'month': ['2023-10-01'] * 4,
    'working_days': [14, 15, 12, 17],
    'type': ['resource'] * 4
})

tasks = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'month': ['2023-10-01'] * 3,
    'working_days': [24, 27, 7],
    'type': ['task'] * 3
})

# Here I combined your datasets
combined = pd.concat([resources, tasks]).reset_index(drop=True)

# You need initialize an empty list to collect results
results = []

# Then use a loop through each task
for idx, row in combined[combined['type'] == 'task'].iterrows():
    task_id = row['id']
    task_working_days_needed = row['working_days']

    # Then another loop to iterate through resources
    for jdx, jrow in combined[combined['type'] == 'resource'].iterrows():
        resource_id = jrow['id']
        resource_working_days = jrow['working_days']

        if task_working_days_needed <= 0:
            # If the  requirements for the task are met, I set a break out of the inner loop
            break

        if resource_working_days <= 0:
            # If the resource has no available days I continue to the next resource
            continue

        # Then assign as many days as possible from the resource to the task
        days_to_assign = min(task_working_days_needed, resource_working_days)

        results.append({
            'id_task': task_id,
            'id_resource': resource_id,
            'days': days_to_assign
        })

        # Finally update remaining working_days_needed for the task and the resource
        task_working_days_needed -= days_to_assign
        combined.loc[jdx, 'working_days'] -= days_to_assign  # Update the combined DataFrame

results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(results_df)
```

[image]